# Apex column header based on if condition

Tags: apex

I'm trying to have the column header populate a label based on a variable indication. Indication can carry "Crohn's (Fistulizing)" or "Ulcerative Colitis".
I need the header to use custom label "JC_CM_DSA_SCORE_CROHNS" if indicaton = "Crohn's.." or use "JC_CM_DSA_Score_UC" if indication = "Ulcer.."

This is what I have so far:

```
<apex:column >
            <!-- Needs to be based on the patients indication -->
            <apex:facet name="header" ><b>{!$Label.JC_CM_DSA_SCORE_CROHNS}</b></apex:facet>
            {!IF(oAccount.Indication__r!=null,mapAccountDecrypted[oAccount.Gender__c],'')}
</apex:column>
```

Answer (score 6):

You just need to use an if statement within the header label itself

```
 <apex:column >
    <!-- Needs to be based on the patients indication -->
    <apex:facet name="header" >
        <b>
            {!IF(<ObjectName>.Indication__c=='Crohn's..',$Label.JC_CM_DSA_SCORE_CROHNS, $Label.JC_CM_DSA_Score_UC)}
        </b>
    </apex:facet>
    {!IF(oAccount.Indication__r!=null,mapAccountDecrypted[oAccount.Gender__c],'')}
</apex:column>
```

Take note that this is assuming `Indication__c`only has two values "Chrons.." and "Ulcerative", if it has more than two values, you might need to use nested IF statements.

Comment: please mark as best answer if this solves your issue. Thanks

Comment: I don't see the check mark that comes up under the arrows, not sure why... @Sean Soriano

Comment: You might be using a different account since the user who asked the question was user29247.

Comment: For more than two values, use a CASE statement.